# 손님, 여러분 - 우리 채팅방에 오세요!

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to point out that, like all SE sites, we have a chat room:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41465/korean-language

It has been a bit quiet in there. But as the site gets more visits, hopefully more people will pop in to say hello.

If you're new to the site, feel free to introduce yourself in chat!

The chat room is also a great place for any discussion that doesn't fit in the space of a few comments.